# how to import a function from a file who import functions from a other file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

i need to import functions from a file who already import functions from a other file ,
this is the code for the imported file :

```py
from sql_csv import *
from Drive_API import *
def cloudSaver () :
    sqlQueryResultExporter()
    fromMachineToCloud()
    pass

def cloudLoader () :
    fromCloudToMachine()
    sqlTableUpdater()
    pass
```

and this is the code of the main file :

```py
from Api.scyncronaser import *
cloudSaver()
```

directory are something like this :

- MainDir :

  - main.py
  - Api :

    - scyncronaser.py

Comment: How are you running your program? This may affect the way you need to write your imports. Generally you can get your imports to work by modifying the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, but this is usually managed by tools like pyenv or virtualenv

Comment: Everything from sql_csv, Drive_API, and scyncronaser should be right there in `main`, then? Indiscriminate `*`-imports are unwise… can you reference just what you need?

Comment: Why are you ending your functions with `pass`? That's only needed as a placeholder for empty blocks.

Comment: What problem are you having? I think this code should work, although the main file will import all the names from `sql_srv` and `Drive_API`

Comment: I just did this program as example so it look useless but is just to give a idea

Comment: The problem is when it import the scyncronaser functions ,i get a error because even the scyncronaser need to import a other modules (other python files who are in the same dir